# Seeking a proof that the residual field of the decomposition field is equal to the base residual field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integrally closed integral domain, $K$ its fraction field, $L$ a finite Galois extension of $K$, and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
Assume that $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $A$ and that $\mathfrak P$ is a prime ideal of $B$ above $\mathfrak p$. Let $\bar K$ be the fraction field of $A/\mathfrak p$, and $\bar L$ be the fraction field of $B/\mathfrak P$. So, $\bar K$ embeds naturally into $\bar L$.

The decomposition group $\mathcal D$ of $\mathfrak P$ in $L$ is the set of automorphisms of Gal($L$/$K$) that leave $\mathfrak P$ globally invariant, and the decomposition field $Z$ of $(L/K, \mathfrak P)$ is the fixed field of $\mathcal D$.

In Bourbaki (Élements de mathématiques, Algèbre commutative, fascicule XXX, Hermann, 1964, p. 53 cor. 4), it is shown that the image $\bar Z$ of $Z$ in $\bar L$ is $\bar K$, but I haven't understood well the demonstration, and anyway, I am seeking a simpler proof. This is the object of my question.

The following additional theorems could be used, if wished, in the simpler proof I am looking for :

1) Every two prime ideals of $B$ above $\mathfrak p$ are conjugated to any one of them (meaning that every prime ideal above $\mathfrak p$ is of the form $\sigma \mathfrak P$ for some $\sigma\in {\rm Gal}(L/K)$).

2)Frobenius theorem : the natural homomorphism $\sigma \mapsto \bar \sigma$ is surjective $\mathcal D \to {\rm Aut}(\bar L/\bar K)$.

EDIT: by "image of $Z$ in $L$", it is meant the fraction field of the image by the canonical projection of the integral closure of $A$ in $Z$, in the same way as $\bar K$ and $\bar L$ are obtained from $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the proof given in Bourbaki -- I hope it is not the same as the following one: first one can pass to the localized ring extension $B_p|A_p$, since the decomposition group and the residue fields do not change under this process. Let $C:=B\cap Z$, and $P = {\mathfrak P} \cap C$. One can now assume that $p$ is is the unique maximal ideal of $A$. Consequently the prime ideals $P_1,\ldots ,P_{r-1},P$ lying above $p$ in $C$ are maximal too, and are **all** maximal ideals of $C$. In particular they are pairwise coprime, which implies

$I:=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{r-1}P_k=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{r-1}P_k$.

Consequently $I+P=C$, since otherwise $I\subseteq P$, which gives the contradiction $P_k\subseteq P$ for some $k$.

To prove equality of the residue fields $\overline{K}$ and $\overline{Z}$ one has to show that for every $c\in C\setminus P$ there exists some $a\in A$ such that $c-a\in P$.

Chose $d^\prime\in I$ and $e^\prime\in P$ such that $d^\prime+e^\prime=1$. Multiplication by $c$ leads to $c=d^\prime c+e^\prime c=:d+e$, $d\in I\setminus P$ and $e\in P$.

Let $\sigma_1:=\mathrm{id},\sigma_2,\ldots ,\sigma_r$ be representatives of the left cosets in $\mathrm{Gal}(L|K)/\mathcal{D}$. For $k\neq 1$ one then has
$\sigma_k(d)\in P$, since $\sigma_k(d)\not\in P$ would imply $d\not\in\sigma_k^{-1}(P)=P_\ell$ and thus $\ell=1$, which is not possible for $k\neq 1$.

Finally define $a:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^r\sigma_k(d)$; $a$ is the trace of $d$ in the extension $Z|K$, thus lies in $K$. Moreover it satisfies

$c-a=d+e-\sum\limits_{k=1}^r\sigma_k(d)=e-\sum\limits_{k=2}^r\sigma_k(d)\in P$

as desired.

Comment: Beautiful. Can I ask you how you hit on that.

Comment: N.B: I have edited a bit your post to make it somewhat more understandable.

Comment: I don't remember where I saw this proof for the first time. Probably in a seminar on Valuation Theory given by Franz-Viktor Kuhlmann in the 1980s. He also told me that many existing proofs, although following essentially the same line of arguments, are just too complicated at one or the other point -- see for example the proof in Zariski-Samuel, volume 2. Anyway there should also be a simple proof in Abhyankar's book "Ramification theoretic methods in Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: Hagen Knaf. I found an apparent problem in this proof : it works well if $Z$ is a Galois extension of $K$, but if it is not, $\sigma_k^{-1}(P)$ may not even be included in $Z$. Have you a mean to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Hagen Knaf. I thing I have overcome the issue. I have edited your post again. Can you check carefully if this is correct ? Note: it is likely to be true that the Galois group permute the $P_k$ (as you originally wrote), but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: @MikeTeX I'm not sure you should keep editing this post. Why not copy it, make your changes, and post another answer (that could even be Community Wiki if you're not sure about reputation, etc)? You *are* significantly changing it, which is generally to be avoided.

Comment: Thx for this advice, and for having reverting the edit. It is better to let Hagen Knaf add something in his post or in comments, if he wish.

Comment: It is true that in general $K\subseteq Z$ is not Galois. But one does not need that: all the computations are taking place within $L$.

Comment: Hagen Knaf. The problem is: how do you justify that $\sigma_k^{-1}(P) = P_\ell$, as you wrote near the end of your answer ? This is a known theorem if $Z$ is Galois (as I wrote in appendix of my question), but if $Z$ is not, some automorphisms $\sigma$ send $C$ to $\sigma C$, with $C\subseteq Z \not = \sigma C\subseteq \sigma Z$.